# Directly read a specific subdirectory from a zip file [Java]

Tags: java, zip, zipinputstream, directorystream

I would like to directly read the files from a subdirectory which is in a zip file.
Is there a more convenient way to do it without iterating through all entries?
The structure of the zip file is always the same, only the files in the subdirectory are different.

Zip file looks like this: 
zipfile.zip 
 -----folder1 
 --------file1 
 --------file2

 -----folder2 
 --------file3 
 --------file4

So I would to directly create a DirectoryStream for lets sat folder1 and work with tho files. I am asking if there is a more convenient way without iterating through all entries.

Cheers

Comment: Unless you know the file names, I don't think it's possible without iterating all entries.

Comment: @Patrick I only know the names of the folders